# How can I search multiple fields and count nulls for all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an easy way to count nulls in all fields in a table without writing 40+ very similar, but slightly different, queries?  I would think there is some kind of statistics maintained for all tables, and this may be the easiest way to go with it, but I don't know for sure.  Thoughts, anyone?  Thanks!!

BTW, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Can you post the table structure with some sample data?

Comment: Nope, You have to write a `COUNT()` for each field, but you can write them in a single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you consider this simple or not, but this will total the NULLs by column in a table.

```
DECLARE @table sysname;
SET @table = 'MyTable'; --replace this with your table name
DECLARE @colname sysname;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE COLS CURSOR FOR
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = @table;

SET @sql = 'SELECT ';

OPEN COLS;
FETCH NEXT FROM COLS INTO @colname;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'COUNT(CASE WHEN ' + @colname + ' IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS ' + @colname + '_NULLS,'
    FETCH NEXT FROM COLS INTO @colname;
END;

CLOSE COLS;
DEALLOCATE COLS;

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql) - 1) --trim tailing ,
SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM ' + @table;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I am curious to see how your script works. When I enter my table name, I get this error message: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0 Cannot assign a default value to a local variable. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 10 Must declare the scalar variable "@table".

Comment: Whoops, I was wrong.  I am actually using SQL Server 2005.  I think that is part of the problem, squillman.  How can I modify your script to work on 2005?

Comment: You could do this without using a cursor.

Comment: Yeah!  That works.  I Googled it and thought it was something like that, but I didn't know exactly what to fix.  Now, I am trying to add a date range, with the field name 'ASOFDATE' but I can't get it working.  I'll try again tomorrow.  Thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN field01 IS NULL THEN 1 END) +
        COUNT( CASE WHEN field02 IS NULL THEN 1 END) +
        ... 
        COUNT( CASE WHEN field40 IS NULL THEN 1 END) as total_nulls
```

Comment: Thanks Kaepora but I have read-rights only.  That could work Juan.  Finally, @squillman, I am curious to see how your script works.  When I enter my table name, I get this error message: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@table".

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40578126/4722913) will return a table containing the name of each column of a specified table. (@tab is the name of the table you're trying to count NULLs in.)

You can loop through the column names, count NULLs in each column, and add the result to a total running count.